# Howto place footnote next to equation

Tags: equations, footnotes

Consider the following fragment

```
... To fulfil this requirement, $y_\infty$ is set to the lowest value 
of $y\left(\tau_\text{max}\right)$ and $-\max\left|y\right|$
multiplied by $1+\epsilon_\text{mach}$ \footnote{$\epsilon_\text{mach}$ is
the smallest number such that $\epsilon_\text{mach} + 1 > 1$. The
existence of such a number comes from the finite precision of the
computer}, if $y\left(\tau_\text{max}\right)<0$. Otherwise ...
```

How can I avoid the footnote digit appearing as an exponent. This sentence is packed with information so it is tricky to add this explanation.

Comment: don't associate footnotes with matematical contents. It will simply confuse your readers. Rewrite the text and if you still feel the need then attach the footnote to some text instead.

Comment: And please do not use `_\text{mach}`, it will come out wrong in an italic context (like inside a theorem). Use `_{\textup{mach}}` or `_{\textnormal{mach}}`. The fact that `_\text{...}` work without and extra set of `{}`'s is just a stroke of luck, should not be depended upon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid footnotes to math material (and avoid footnotes in general).

In this case you should at least have the footnote marker *after* the comma, but it's just less confusing.

I'd reword the paragraph, taking also into account the fact that *ε*<sub>mach</sub> is an important ingredient in the formula; footnotes should only contain material that can be skipped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tsub}[1]{_{\textnormal{#1}}}

\textheight=4cm % just not to waste space

\begin{document}

To fulfil this requirement, $y_\infty$ is set to the lowest value
of $y(\tau\tsub{max})$ and $-\max\lvert y\rvert$ multiplied by
$1+\epsilon\tsub{mach}$, if $y\left(\tau_\text{max}\right)<0$.
We denote by $\epsilon\tsub{mach}$ the smallest number such that
$\epsilon\tsub{mach} + 1 > 1$; its existence is ensured by the 
finite precision of the computer. Otherwise ...

\bigskip

To fulfil this requirement, $y_\infty$ is set to the lowest value
of $y(\tau\tsub{max})$ and $-\max\lvert y\rvert$
multiplied by $1+\epsilon\tsub{mach}$,\footnote{$\epsilon\tsub{mach}$ is
the smallest number such that $\epsilon\tsub{mach} + 1 > 1$. The
existence of such a number comes from the finite precision of the
computer} if $y(\tau\tsub{max})<0$. Otherwise ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed the wrong `\left`–`\right` pairs and defined a correct command for textual subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following rewrite that does not need a footnote:

```
... multiplied by $1+\epsilon_\textnormal{mach}$ where $\epsilon_\textnormal{mach}$ is the smallest number such that $\epsilon_\textnormal{mach} + 1 > 1$.
```

I fully agree with daleif that footnote markers (whether they are numerical or letters or symbolics) are just confusing when applied to mathematical formulæ.

Comment: I would, but the sentence continues with an "if", which is more important information.

Comment: @user877329 then place the comment in (...)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternatives:
The first uses a different symbol to indicate the footnote. The second re-words the sentences to eliminate a use of footnote.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}

\DefineFNsymbols*{lamport}{\dagger\ddagger\S\P\|%
{**}{\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}
}

\begin{document}

... To fulfil this requirement, $y_\infty$ is set to the lowest value 
of $y\left(\tau_\text{max}\right)$ and $-\max\left|y\right|$
multiplied by $(1+\epsilon_\text{mach})$ \footnote{$\epsilon_\text{mach}$ is
the smallest number such that $\epsilon_\text{mach} + 1 > 1$. The
existence of such a number comes from the finite precision of the
computer}, if $y\left(\tau_\text{max}\right)<0$. Otherwise ...

\vspace{5mm}
... To fulfil this requirement, $y_\infty$ is set to the lowest value 
of $y\left(\tau_\text{max}\right)$ and $-\max\left|y\right|$
multiplied by $(1+\epsilon_\text{mach})$ if $y\left(\tau_\text{max}\right)<0$.
Here $\epsilon_\text{mach}$ is the smallest number such that $\epsilon_\text{mach} + 1 > 1$. The
existence of such a number comes from the finite precision of the
computer. Otherwise ...

\end{document}
```

The footmisc documentation is obtained from http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/footmisc/footmisc.pdf